# ValueError when transmitting a file titled in Arabic over a Python tcp socket

Tags: python, sockets, arabic, valueerror, non-english

I'm building a socket program to transmit files between two computers. Files with English titles are transmitted successfully, but when I try to send Arabic titled files (eg وثيقة.docx), I get a long list of ValueErrors, starting with:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 2: b'.docx000000000000000000010000001'
```

inva`lid literal for int() with base 2: b'10001PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00\xe0'`

My code is:
Server:

```
import socket

serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = 'localhost'
port = 9000
serversock.bind((host,port))
filename = ""
serversock.listen(10)
print("Waiting for a connection.....")

clientsocket, addr = serversock.accept()
print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))

while True:
    try:
        size = clientsocket.recv(16) # Note that you limit your filename length to 255 bytes.
        if not size:
            clientsocket, addr = serversock.accept()
            print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
            continue
        size = int(size, 2)
        print('SIZE', size)
        filename = clientsocket.recv(size)
        print('filename', filename)
        filesize = clientsocket.recv(32)
        print('FILESIZE', filesize, 'TYPE', type(filesize))
        filesize = int(filesize, 2) ##########
        file_to_write = open(filename, 'wb')
        chunksize = 4096
        while filesize > 0:
            if filesize < chunksize:
                chunksize = filesize
            data = clientsocket.recv(chunksize)
            file_to_write.write(data)
            filesize -= len(data)

        file_to_write.close()
        print('File (%s) received successfully' % filename.decode('utf-8'))
    except ValueError as verr:
        print(verr)
        #continue
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('FileNotFoundError')
        #continue
serversock.close()
```

Client:

import

```
 socket
import os
from file_walker import files_to_transmit

def transmit(host, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
        directory = files_to_transmit()
        for file in directory:
            filename = file
            size = len(filename.split('/')[-1]) # split() to get bare file name to transmit to server
            size = bin(size)[2:].zfill(16) # encode filename size as 16 bit binary
            s.send(size.encode('utf-8'))
            s.send(filename.split('/')[-1].encode('utf-8')) # split() to get bare file name

            filename = file
            filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
            filesize = bin(filesize)[2:].zfill(32) # encode filesize as 32 bit binary
            s.send(filesize.encode('utf-8'))

            file_to_send = open(filename, 'rb')

            l = file_to_send.read()
            s.sendall(l)
            file_to_send.close()
            print('File Sent')

        s.close()
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print('ConnectionRefusedError: Server may not be running')

    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

transmit('localhost', 9000)
```

What is the problem here? Please help.

Comment: can you paste the complete error, and the string you are getting directly from the socket.

Comment: Got a connection from ('127.0.0.1', 39604)
SIZE 15
filename b'Untitled 1.docx'
FILESIZE b'00000000000000000001000000011110' TYPE <class 'bytes'>
File (Untitled 1.docx) received successfully
SIZE 10
filename b'\xd8\xad\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a'
FILESIZE b'.docx000000000000000000010000001' TYPE <class 'bytes'>
invalid literal for int() with base 2: b'.docx000000000000000000010000001'
invalid literal for int() with base 2: b'10001PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00\xe0'
invalid literal for int() with base 2: b'6mN\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b'

Comment: Please add the error to the question(properly edited). It should be the full Traceback error.

Comment: The problem isn't the name of the file. Look at the error message. It is expecting a filesize that is a number and your code is sending `b'.docx000000000000000000010000001'`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. But how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send the size in unicode character of the title, and then try to send it encoded in utf-8. For example with your example:

```
title = 'وثيقة.docx'
print(len(title), len(title.encode('utf8')))
```

gives

```
10 15
```

The peer will only use 10 bytes for the file name, and will use the remaining 5 as the beginning of the file size. And will choke for `.docx` not being the beginning of a binary number. What happens...

Fix is easy, build the byte string before computing its length:

```
    ...
    for file in directory:
        filename = file.split('/')[-1].encode('utf_8') # split() to get bare file name
        size = len(filename)

        size = bin(size)[2:].zfill(16) # encode filename size as 16 bit binary
        s.send(size.encode('utf-8'))
        s.send(filename) 
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simalar problem faced out in my experience.
What i'm suggesting is to use an algorithm to encode and decode files like base64.

Somewhere in your program you're reading the file to save him in memory and send in second steps. Well instead just reading encode also

```
import base64

with open("yourfile.ext", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

Obviously in other side you need to decode and write on disk. You can encode and decode also the title of file to avoid *ValueError*